# SQL Left Join Return Latest Row

Tags: php, sql, left-join

Two tables, with a left join. For ease table 1 and table 2.

Table 1 contains a list of people and their current status, table 2 is all of their "invites". All im trying to do as part of the join is show in a list all the current "people" and then the LATEST invite status (from table 2) so return a single row from table 2.

I have everything working... but its duplicating for example if a person has had multiple invites it will put them twice on the list. I just want to limit it to

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.fieldname as table1fielname table2.fieldname [more fields] 
        FROM xxx 
        LEFT JOIN xxx on table1.sharedid=table2.sharedid  
        WHERE XXX LIMIT 1 ";`
```

Obvioulsy the limit 1 doesnt do what its supposed to. I have tried adding additional select statements in brackets but being honest it just breaks everything and im not an expert at all.

Comment: use DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY if you want to avoid duplicates

Comment: If you only need one field from table2, you could do it with a subquery that is designed to select first, and then order the subquery by the latest date. `SELECT table1.fieldname, (SELECT FIRST table2.invitestatus FROM table2 WHERE table1.shareid=table2.shareid ORDER BY table2.date desc) AS InviteStatus FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Thanks for your suggestion, although im still struggling to get it to work - your way or you saying remove the join? Or keep it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks although doesnt seem to work, If i use distinct they are already distinct as in the table two can have multiple statuses so will only remove same statuses. As for group i tried to group but that then seems to group the entire results.

Comment: @JackBramhall If there is only one field you need from table 2, and you don't need to join anything else from it, you could remove the join and just subquery it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert too but I'll try. Have you tried to use DISTINCT?

For exemple:

SELECT DISTINCT column_name1,column_name2

FROM table_name; [...]

It normally delete double matches.

Here are the links:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php

Comment: If could post the screen shots may help to Answer the Question

Comment: Hello, unfortunately DISTINCT isnt working. As for screenshots - I have put my code above? The only thing i missed is then the echo of the data.

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
  <td>".$row["statusname"]."</td>
  <td>".$row["trialstatus"]."</td>

Answer (score 0):

Give example data. And use good table and column names. For example:

(this returns all rows that satisfy the join):

```
WITH people(ppl_id,ppl_name,status) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Arthur','active'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Tricia','active'
),   invites(ppl_id,inv_id,inv_date) AS (
          SELECT 1,1, DATE '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, DATE '2017-01-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, DATE '2017-01-08'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, DATE '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, DATE '2017-01-08'
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM people
JOIN invites USING(ppl_id)
ORDER BY 1
;
ppl_id|ppl_name|status|inv_id|inv_date
     1|Arthur  |active|     1|2017-01-01
     1|Arthur  |active|     3|2017-01-08
     1|Arthur  |active|     2|2017-01-07
     2|Tricia  |active|     2|2017-01-08
     2|Tricia  |active|     1|2017-01-01
```

But we want only 'Arthur' with '2017-01-08' and 'Tricia' with '2017-01-08'.

With any database that supports ANSI 99, you could try with a temporary table containing the newest invitation date per "people id", and join that temporary table with the invitations table. We call that table `newest_invite_date`, and, apparently, it does what we expect it to do:

```
WITH people(ppl_id,ppl_name,status) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Arthur','active'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Tricia','active'
),   invites(ppl_id,inv_id,inv_date) AS (
          SELECT 1,1, DATE '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, DATE '2017-01-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, DATE '2017-01-08'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, DATE '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, DATE '2017-01-08'
),   newest_invite_date(ppl_id,inv_date) AS (
          SELECT ppl_id,MAX(inv_date)
          FROM   invites
          GROUP BY ppl_id              
) 
SELECT 
  people.ppl_id
, people.ppl_name
, people.status
, newest_invite_date.inv_date
FROM people
JOIN newest_invite_date USING(ppl_id)
ORDER BY 1
;
ppl_id|ppl_name|status|inv_date
     1|Arthur  |active|2017-01-08
     2|Tricia  |active|2017-01-08
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Happy playing ...
Marco the Sane